# Display linux sleep state

Tags: power-management, suspend

I have built up a new AlmaLinux 9 system which has a power LED that is normally on (constant).  After a while I notice the power led slow blinks.

According to what I found online this indicates the host is "sleeping".  However, the host is still responsive (I have an SSH shell open and can execute commands) - yet the power led keeps blinking.

Is there a low(er)-power state which leaves Linux responsive, yet still "sleeping"?  How can I tell the current state?  How can I wake it up fully (so the power led stops blinking)?

Comment: same with vga-connector. about 2-3 hour after uodate

Comment: what have you tried in order to wake it up?

Comment: I tried issued commands on the CLI via SSH.  It appears to be "awake" - which is why I asked how can I display the state that Linux thinks it's in